# How to get bash indexes of parameters array?

Tags: bash, shell, array, parameter

I want indexes of parameters,

and can get it by dummy var:

```
dummy=( $@ )
echo ${!dummy[@]}
```

but is there straight way to get them, something like

```
$!@ ... not working
$!* ... not working
```

... or something like that?

NOTE: original function that i want to have without arr var is this:

```
function indexof()
{  search="$1"; shift; arr=( $@ ) 
   for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do [ "$search" == "${arr[$i]}" ] && return $i; done
   return -1
}
```

Comment: Note that `arr=( $@ )` will split args that contain IFS (by default whitespace); if you didn't dis-want this form entirely you would want `arr=( "$@" )`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 ,  yes, but this is first time that i see that parrametters array is not as other arrays (no syntax for getting indexes), or maybe indexes was meant for associative arrays initialy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate from the number of arguments:

```
seq ${#@}
```

Comment: nice, how to tell seq to go 0..n-1 instead 1..n like original code do

Comment: it's very hard: `seq 0 $((${#@}-1))`

Comment: ok, so if there is no direct bash way like $!@... seq seems better than dummy var, marking this as answer.

Comment: `$#` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a dummy array. You can use a counter variable:

```
indexof() {
    search="$1"; shift
    i=0
    for arg; do
        [ "$search" = "$arg" ] && return $i
        ((i++))
    done
    return -1
}
```

Note that `for arg; do` uses `"$@"` by default, that's why `in "$@"` can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, in `zsh`, the indexOf functionality is with:

```
$ set foo bar baz bar foo
$ echo $@[(i)bar] $@[(I)bar]
2 4
```

(`$2` is the *first* match (using the `i` subscript flag), `$4` the *last* match (`I` subscript flag)).

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use the 'arithmetic-for' form:

```
indexof(){ search=$1; shift 
    for(( i=1; i<=$#; i++ )); do [[ $search == ${!i} ]] && return $i; done
    return -1 # as an old LISPer I'd prefer 0 for the notfound case
}
```

Not particularly better (IMO) but different.